# How do I introduce a "light mode", in which not all plugins are loaded?

Tags: invocation

My Vim config includes [plugins that try to handle current project, build tags, etc](http://goo.gl/dQVhzo). This is quite useful for my daily programming in Vim, but it's just annoying when I use Vim for some quick edits, like:

- edit a git commit message;
- edit a shell command when I type <kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+e</kbd> in zsh or bash;
- etc.

I don't like the `--noplugins` either, since I still want to take advantage of some plugins in quick-edit mode, such as surround, easy-motion, and lots of others.

So, I want to have some "light mode" (or "quick mode"), in which some of the plugins will be bypassed, but not all of them.

My first idea was to have some special command-line argument, which I'd parse in vimscript, but quick googling shows that it's currently impossible in vimscript (awful sad, by the way).

My second idea is to set some environment variable when running vim, like this:

```
$ VIM_LIGHT_MODE=1 vim
```

This works in git:

```
$ git config --global core.editor 'VIM_LIGHT_MODE=1 vim'
```

But if I do `EDITOR='VIM_LIGHT_MODE=1 vim'`, and type <kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+e</kbd> in the shell, it doesn't work:

```
edit-command-line:13: command not found: VIM_LIGHT_MODE=1
```

Then I tried this: `EDITOR="bash -c 'VIM_LIGHT_MODE=1 vim'"`, but it fails as well:

```
vim': -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

(To be honest, this one looks particularly weird, it seems I misunderstand how exactly `$EDITOR` is used, and I'll be glad if someone explains what's going on here)

All other experiments failed as well.

The only hack I can think of is to set some `servername`, like:

```
$ vim --servername VIM_LIGHTWEIGHT_MODE
```

And then check `v:servername` in vimscript, but this is a *total* hack: this is not what servername is for, at all.

So is there a cleaner way to achieve what I want?

Comment: You can use `env`: `EDITOR='env VIM_LIGHT_MODE=1 vim'`.

Comment: You can also use another initialization file and run `vim` as `vim -u .vimrc-light`.

Comment: Oh.. Your both ideas are cool, thanks. And I wasn't aware of `env` at all, my shell-fu is still too weak.
Consider writing it as an answer, so that I'll be able to accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are (at least) two possibilities:

1. use `env`:

   ```
   EDITOR='/usr/bin/env VIM_LIGHT_MODE=1 vim'
   ```
2. use `vim` with another initialization file, say `.vimrc-light`:

   ```
   EDITOR='/usr/bin/vim -u ~/.vimrc-light'
   ```

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer is certainly better, I'd like to discuss `EDITOR="bash -c 'VIM_LIGHT_MODE=1 vim'"`. The problem here is that `EDITOR` is invoked with arguments, and the arguments passed to `bash -c` do not get forwarded automatically to `vim`. You need to use `"$@"`:

```
EDITOR="bash -c 'VIM_LIGHT_MODE=1 vim \"\$@\"'
```

However, the first argument after the command in `bash -c` is `$0`, which is not part of `$@`, so you need to use a placeholder argument:

```
EDITOR="bash -c 'VIM_LIGHT_MODE=1 vim \"\$@\" lightvim'
```

With these pitfalls, it's not a good option, but workable nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your first idea is possible, in an elegant way too.
You can create a user defined command and then call vim with the `+` syntax.

Just define a custom user command in your `.vimrc` file like so:

```
command! CustomUserCommandName AnyVimCommandToExecute
```

Then from the command line you can start vim like so:

```
$ vim +CustomUserCommandName
```

I used this in my `.vimrc` for easy note taking, like so:

```
" Note Taking {{{
command! Note execute "normal \<Plug>VimwikiMakeDiaryNote"
command! Notes execute "normal \<Plug>VimwikiDiaryIndex" | execute "normal \<Plug>VimwikiDiaryGenerateLinks"
" }}}
```

This allows for calling it with this`vim +Note`. Then make a shell alias in your shells `rc` file, to allow even easier calling. In my `.bashrc` file I alias the above vim commands like this:

```
alias note="vim +Note"
alias notes="vim +Notes"
```

### Sample solution

In your case you could write something along these lines in your `.vimrc` file:

```
command! LightMode let g:lightmode=1
```

Then test for light mode however you want on per plugin basis or groups of plugins, etc... using a vim `if` statement similar to this in your `.vimrc` file:

```
if exists("g:lightMode")
    " Do something cool with vim 
endif
```

### Things to Note

- The `!` after the vim command `command!` means that this will overwrite any similarly defined commands with the same name. This is preferable.
- The `CustomUserCommandName` **MUST** have the first letter capitalized
- You may not want to pollute your global scope with `g:` you can use `s:` or any scope that fits your needs.